# AWS Cloud9 Lambda installing node.js modules

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, promise, aws-lambda, aws-cloud9

I'm having issues trying to install node modules in my lambda project in AWS Cloud9.

I ran the commands

```
npm install --save request
npm install --save request-promise
```

I keep getting "Error: Cannot find module 'request-promise'".

I have the following code.

```
var rp = require('request-promise');
```

It is structured like this

-Lambda Env

--getMergedProducts

--node_modules

Comment: I don't really know what it is but can you try this ? sudo npm install -g request-promise--unsafe-perm=true --allow-root

Comment: That didn't work, i got an error and looked in the logs and found this.
5039 error peerinvalid The package request does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
5045 error code EPEERINVALID
5046 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Comment: sorry bro please try it again like      sudo npm install -g request-promise --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root

Comment: I forgot to give a space between promies(here)--unsafe

Comment: i tried it with spaces. Its the same issue.

 ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "request-promise" "--unsafe-perm=true" "--allow-root"
npm ERR! cwd /home/ec2-user/environment
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.48
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.6
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ec2-user/environment/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0

And when i look in the log file. I see the error above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how Lambda should be used.
I spoke with an AWS solutions architect and he set things straight for me.

> Remember that each function is intended to stand on its own, so it needs to be packaged on its own. Each function would have its own package.json and node_modules as each function runs in its own container(s).
>
> Your approach assumes that all of your functions run on the same infrastructure, which is not the case in the serverless world. Global modules (beyond what is packaged in the Lambda runtime) do not exist.
>
> Be sure to read:
>   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/best-practices.html and
>   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html

And I tested this by moving the node_modules folder from the environment folder to the lambda project folder and it worked!